# Dovecot hangs on all logins including local telnet

Tags: debian, dovecot, imap

After a routine system upgrade (Debian testing) yesterday, clients stopped being able to connect to our mailserver's imapd. Following the troubleshooting/test guide http://wiki.dovecot.org/TestInstallation, I tried telnetting in on port 143 from both the localhost and a remote server. In both cases, the connection establishes but I get no response when I enter a login command. I also tried the SSL login with the same effect.

Nothing is being written to syslog, auth, or mail.* except restart information when I restart Dovecot. No firewall is running, and iptables --list shows all chains unconditionally accept. And yes, Dovecot is actually running:-)

I tried reverting my config to the default. Same problem.

Dovecot was not upgraded during the system upgrade. These were the changes made by the upgrade: http://pastebin.com/708X9wTr

Any help appreciated. I'm tearing what's left of my hair out over this.

Comment: What is the auth backend used? Is this still working?

Comment: Most everything seems to point to the fact that dovecot isn't responsible, it's usually quite verbose,especially when things go pear shaped.

Comment: All verbosity is at max. Auth backend is passdb but I also tried unix.

Comment: Hmmm...attempting to attach to the running server with gdb hangs...this is not normal. Debsums verifies all hashes of dovecot and its constituent parts.

Comment: Running Dovecot with strace reveals that it was being held up by attempting to stat a hanging sshfs mount in a user's home directory. Forcing this unmounted resolves my problem. The user had a sshfs in their crontab, so the reboot post-update caused the immediate issue, not the update itself. I have no clue why it was statting that file.

I hate computers.

Answer (score 1):

Running Dovecot with strace reveals that it was being held up by attempting to stat a hanging sshfs mount in a user's home directory. Forcing this unmounted resolves my problem. The user had a sshfs in their crontab, so the reboot post-update caused the immediate issue, not the update itself. I have no clue why it was statting that file. I hate computers.