# Dovecot does not react on telnet

Tags: dovecot

So I installed dovecot and tried to connect via telnet to port 143.
Dovecot is configured to listen:

```
> doveconf listen protocols
listen = *
protocols =  imap
```

is running:

```
> ps auxf | grep dovecot
root     19123  0.0  0.4   2984  1784 ?        Ds   16:14   0:00 /usr/sbin/dovecot -c /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
```

and is listening:

```
> netstat -ptan | grep ':143'
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      19123/dovecot
```

But after connecting to it, it doesn't greet nor react to a login try:

```
> telnet 127.0.0.1 imap
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
A1 LOGIN user pass
```

Nothing happens!

I activated all debuggin options:

```
> egrep -v '^\s*(#|$)' /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-logging.conf           
auth_debug_passwords = yes
mail_debug = yes
plugin {
}
> doveconf auth_debug_passwords mail_debug
auth_debug_passwords = yes
mail_debug = yes
```

but I don't see anything beside the startup message in the syslog

```
> tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep dovecot
Feb  1 16:14:28 hostname dovecot: master: Dovecot v2.1.7 starting up (core dumps disabled)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that this is the same problem as [Dovecot hangs on all logins including local telnet](https://serverfault.com/questions/500980/dovecot-hangs-on-all-logins-including-local-telnet).
I have an open nfs mount with a currently offline server. After disabeling the mount dovecot startet flawlessly.
Also http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Mountpoints might help.